# CSS Help - div over image

Tags: html, css

I'm making a small site for my college project, most of it is complete but I'm stuck on how I should go about adding a feature.

If you go onto a site like http://wallbase.cc/toplist and rollover an image you'll see a little black bar will appear on the bottom of the image showing the dimensions. I want to add this to my website but I don't know what CSS rules to use in order to get the black bar to show ontop of the image, everything else I've tried either goes to the side of the image or floats on the page.

The page will be generated with jQuery + DOM but the end result will look a bit like:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="error" id="pretext">Showing x results</div>
    <div class="image"><img src="imagelink" height="200" width="200" alt="thumb"></img></div>
</div>
```

And my relevant CSS rules:

```
#content {
    background: #FBFBFB;
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 15px;
}

.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about having a master `<div>` with a background image?

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: ('/images/whatever.jpg');">
    <div class="footerBar">[content]</div>
</div>
```

And style them with CSS, or use JavaScript to set the images.

```
.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.footerBar {
    background-color: lightGrey;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: none;
    display: none;
}
.image:hover .footerBar {
    display: block;
}
```

See example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhino/Y6DqA/)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `position: absolute` on the div you want to position over the image.

Answer (score 1):

Rhino's idea is a good one but you'll want to set footerbar's positioon to static so it stays inside the div.image

```
.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url("/images/whatever.jpg");
    position:inline-block;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.footerBar {
    position: static;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: none;
}

<div class="image">
    <div class="footerBar">[content]</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise you'd have to use javascript to find the position of the image relative to the page and absolute position the text where you wanted it with a higher z-index.

Comment: I think they work fine as is, please see the updated code and the jsFiddle demo.  Please let me know if there is something wrong in the code.