# Show text over a image when hovering over it

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I'm working on a project where I want a title to show up upon having the mouse over an image. I have searched stackoverflow for similar cases, tried what was suggested but have not gotten it to work yet.

For example on a pic, I want a text saying "Nutrition" showing up when I put the cursor over it. What would be the easiest way to do this?

I'm new to web developing, not much knowledge when it comes to Javascript/JQuery

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Help - div over image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769830/css-help-div-over-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/eXTYX/

```
<img src="pic.png">
<span>TEXT</span>

span{
    display: none;
}
img{
    width: 500px;
}
img:hover ~ span{
    display: inline;
}
```

This is one way of doing it. No JavaScript is needed ;)

You can even add animation and transitions to it: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/eXTYX/1/

---

As others have also mentioned, you can also use `title` to show a system tooltip. This is very easy to implement, however, you will have no control over how it appears:

```
<img src="pic.png" title="Easy tooltip!">
```

Comment: @user3236461 - You have to be more specific on how "it is not working." Can you post an example on JSFiddle?

Comment: @user3236461 - If you are using the `title` tooltip then yes you are doing it right ;) But one thing I want to tell you that `<img>` doesn't have a closing tag, and doing `<img></img>` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

No JavaScript needed; just use the `title` attribute:

```
<img src="/path/to/image/nutrition.png" title="Nutrition" />
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMatC/).

The `title` attribute also works on any HTML element, so if you want to use it on an image's container to expand the hoverable area, you can.

Comment: when hovering over the image with the cursor, nothing happens

Comment: @user3236461 Please post a minimal example of the problem on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @user3236461 It works for me. Are you sure you're hovering over the actual image, and not the `<article>`?

Comment: My bad... I was expecting a bigger text, didn't notice it. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

When setting your image in html, you can set a title attribute. like the following

```
<img src="happy.gif"  width="10" height="10" Title="I'm happy"/>
```

this is also beneficial for SEO!

Comment: It seems like you are not actually trying the solutions given by multiple people, and giving the same "I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but this just wont work!". If it isn't working say why, and try to be more specific as to why you think it isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

No need for java script just use the `title` see more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

```
<img src="foo/bar" title="foo" alt="bar">
```

Hope this helps